# How to fetch SAML Assertion from ADFS for AWS STS in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs3.0

I need to fetch temporary credentials from AWS STS.
Using below AWS SDK api:

```
AssumeRoleWithSAMLRequest samlreq =new AssumeRoleWithSAMLRequest().withPrincipalArn(principalARN).withRoleArn(roleARN).withSAMLAssertion(SAMLToken);
```

Above API call needs SAML assertion/token from SAML 2.0 compliant ADFS.
My application is in Java. Need sample Java code to retrieve SAML Assertion/Token from ADFS IDP and use it in AWS SDK

Note: I am able to do SAML based federated user SSO to login to AWS console with ADFS and AWS account setup that I am using, just need to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Ritwaj can you please help with this

Comment: Having the same issue. Found articles that tell you to screen-scrape the login form but thats it so far. Doesn't it have a REST API or something?

Comment: Having same problem.. appreciate if anyone with knowledge on this could throw some light..